# Registering back button events not working in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Not getting console when the event happens.i tried a lot, not able to find the issue.Able to get console when i comment the code for remove listner .

```
  const MyComponent = props => {
      const onPopState = event =>{
       console.log(event)
      }
      useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('popstate', onPopState);
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('popstate', onPopState);
        };
      }, []);
    }
```

Comment: It's `popstate` when using `addEventListener` and `onpopstate` when accessing `window.onpopstate`.

Comment: added popstate. but it's only working when i comment the code of removeEventListner

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

````
const MyComponent = props => {
      const handlePopState = event =>{
       console.log(event)
      }
      useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
        };
      }, []);
    } ```
````